# Get text after specific character

Tags: sql, teradata, substr

I have a field in a Teradata database and I want to extract the text after a specific value. I can't use substring as there is sometimes more than 1 space before the text.

**Example 1**

```
Amount changed to Ù95
```

**Example 2**

```
Amount changed to   Ù150
```

I only want to select the number after Ù. So 95 in example 1 and 150 in example 2. I think I need to use REGEXP_SUBSTR but can't work it out.

Comment: `regexp_substr(str,'(?<=Ù).*')` matches everything after, but not including Ù

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
select substring('Amount changed to Ù95',INSTR('Amount changed to Ù95','Ù')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regexp_substr function:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_column_name, 'Amount changed to\s+(\S+)')
FROM your_table;
```